# Remove trailing slash from 2 pages

Tags: asp.net

I am using default.aspx page in a folder. When the page renders in browser it has a trailing slash ie myfolder/mypage/
I want to remove the trailing slash on two specific pages only (for SEO reasons).
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Not sure why its marked down, i've been on it for a day now trying to fix....

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any clean way of removing aspx extension in web forms without performing a major routing change. Thanks all for the feedback too :)